# guava AbstractIterator - duplicate class

Tags: java, gradle, guava

I want to migrate one of our projects from ant+ivy to gradle. When I compile sources using gradle I get this error:

```
...\guava-gwt-14.0.1.jar(com/google/common/collect/AbstractIterator.java):64: error: duplicate class: com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator
public abstract class AbstractIterator<T> extends UnmodifiableIterator<T> {
                ^
...\guava-gwt-14.0.1.jar(com/google/common/base/Optional.java):223: error: cannot access AbstractIterator
        return new AbstractIterator<T>() {
                   ^
  bad source file: ...\guava-gwt-14.0.1.jar(com/google/common/base/AbstractIterator.java)
    file does not contain class com.google.common.base.AbstractIterator
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors
```

I checked that `AbstractIterator.java` is in `com.google.common.collect` and `com.google.common.base` (as wrote in error). How to solve this problem?

**[UPDATE]**

This is my gradle build (very simple - it's a beginning of migration from ant to gradle)

```
apply plugin: 'java'

compileJava.options.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'http://gwtquery-plugins.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo'
    }
    ivy {
        url 'http://ivyrep/shared'
        url 'http://ivyrep/public'
        layout "pattern", { artifact "[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact].[ext]" }
    }
}

// I know that conigurations should be repaired (testCompile, runtime) but this is just the beggining of migration from ant to gradle
dependencies {
    compile 'net.sourceforge.cobertura:cobertura:1.9.4.1'
    compile 'com.google.gwt:gwt-servlet:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.gwt:gwt-user:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.gwt:gwt-dev:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.gwt.inject:gin:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.googlecode.gwtquery:gwtquery:1.3.2'
    compile 'com.googlecode.gwtquery.bundles:gquery-dnd-bundle:1.0.6'
    compile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    compile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5'
    compile 'junit:junit:4.10'
    compile 'org.easytesting:fest-assert-core:2.0M10'
    compile 'xmlunit:xmlunit:1.3'
    compile 'org.reflections:reflections:0.9.9-RC1'
}
```

I should also add that this is a **GWT project**.

**[UPDATE]**

Problem solved. I've excluded guava-gwt from compile scope and it started to work. This is probably not the best solution but it works.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

configurations { guavaGwt }

dependencies {
    guavaGwt 'com.google.guava:guava-gwt:14.0.1'
    // other dependencies
}

task compileGwt (dependsOn: classes) << {
    // [...]
        javaexec {
            main = 'com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler'
            maxHeapSize = '512M'
            classpath {
                [
                    sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs,
                    sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir,
                    sourceSets.main.output.classesDir,
                    sourceSets.main.compileClasspath,
                    configurations.guavaGwt, // USE guava-gwt
                ]
            }
            args =
                    [
                        moduleName,
                        '-war',
                        buildDir,
                        '-logLevel',
                        'INFO',
                        // '-draftCompile' // Speeds up compile with 25%
                    ]
        }
    // [...]
}

compileJava {
    configurations.compile.exclude module:'guava-gwt' // exclude guava-gwt
    // do the job
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `build.gradle` file? Also please check if you don't have both guava and guava-gwt in your classpath.

Comment: Are you modifying your code or your dependencies at the same time you're changing the build tool? It looks like you have both `import com.google.common.base.*` and `import com.google.common.collect.*` in the source file where you use `AbstractIterator`.

Comment: I edited my question. Xaerxes, thanks, I checked it and you're right but those libraries are downloaded transitive. Should I remove ordinary guava lib and use ony gwt version? Frank, I checked it and we don't have this kind of import.

Comment: @Xaerxess, as you can see here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava-gwt/14.0.1, guava-gwt depends on ordinary guava.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem.  Have you had any luck figuring it out?

Comment: The problem occurred because I was using guava-gwt library in 'compile' scope. I changed my gradle build and it started to work. See my edit.

Comment: I initially did the same workaround as you, but ran into problems when deserializing guava classes (i.e. LinkedHashMultimap) in the client-side gwt code. I am also moving from ant to gradle and in the ant build we included guava-gwt at compile time.  I'm thinking I could get rid of this error if I were to keep guava-gwt on the compile classpath.

Comment: As you can see in my code I've removed guava-gwt from compile scope because it is not necessary there. It is used in gwt so I added this to copmileGwt task.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue today, and fixed it by adding this to my gradle build file:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs += ["-sourcepath", ""]
}
```

Thanks for Peter's answer in this post: http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/compilation_fails_when_i_use_guavas_optional_class_duplicate_class_com_google_common_collect_abstractiterator

Answer (score 0):

Some GWT Jars contains classes *and* sources. By default, javac will try to compile sources on the class path, which is probably why you get this error. This should fix it:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs << '-implicit:none'
}
```

PS: Your Ivy repo declaration is overwriting its own URL. Instead you'll want to declare two Ivy repos.

Comment: Peter, you might to be right but it doesn't work (I added this at the beginning of the build.gradle). Still get the same error.

Comment: Try `options.compilerArgs = ["-implicit:none"]`.

Comment: we have the same problem. adding "implicit:none" does not help.

Comment: If you can provide a minimal self-contained sample build that allows to reproduce the problem, I'll investigate further.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser I've put up a minimal self-contained example of the problem on github https://github.com/matheeeny/guava-gwt-gradle-problem.  Please let us know what you can come up with as this is currently a blocker for us moving our build to gradle.

Answer (score 0):

I also came across this error when building a GWT project with maven on ubuntu. A colleague did some research and found the following compiler arg solves the issue:

```
-Xprefer:newer
```